# moderncv - how to adjust the description columns?

Tags: moderncv

So basically the question is in the title. How can I adjust the width of the part where I put info about myself? Currently it looks like this:

[image: What my cv looks like now]

You see how there is weird looking break. How can I extend it so that it expands to certain width? Or so that it fits in one line?

Ok, here's the MWE that's producing the same problem:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{moderncv}
\moderncvtheme[green]{classic}                

% character encoding
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[croatian]{babel}
\usepackage{ucs}                   % replace by the encoding you are using

% adjust the page margins
\usepackage[scale=0.8]{geometry}
%\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3cm}                     % if you want to change the width of the column with the dates
%\AtBeginDocument{\setlength{\maketitlenamewidth}{6cm}}  % only for the classic theme, if you want to change the width of your name placeholder (to leave more space for your address details
%\AtBeginDocument{\recomputelengths}                     % required when changes are made to page layout lengths

% personal data
\firstname{John}
\familyname{Doe}
%\title{Resumé title (optional)}               % optional, remove the line if not wanted
\address{Blabla place 14}{xxxxx Randomcity}    % optional, remove the line if not wanted
\mobile{06548946354}                    % optional, remove the line if not wanted
\phone{2314864464}                      % optional, remove the line if not wanted
%\fax{fax (optional)}                          % optional, remove the line if not wanted
\email{john.doe@some.something.com}                      % optional, remove the line if not wanted
\homepage{http://www.somepage.com}                % optional, remove the line if not wanted
%\extrainfo{additional information (optional)} % optional, remove the line if not wanted
%\photo[64pt]{picture}                         % '64pt' is the height the picture must be resized to and 'picture' is the name of the picture file; optional, remove the line if not wanted
%\quote{Some quote (optional)}                 % optional, remove the line if not wanted

% to show numerical labels in the bibliography; only useful if you make citations in your resume
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\bibliographyitemlabel}{\@biblabel{\arabic{enumiv}}}
\makeatother

% bibliography with mutiple entries
%\usepackage{multibib}
%\newcites{book,misc}{{Books},{Others}}

%\nopagenumbers{}                             % uncomment to suppress automatic page numbering for CVs longer than one page
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%            content
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{Datum i mjesto rođenja}
\cventry{14.01.1955.}{Someplace}{Somecountry}{}{}{}


\section{Poznavanje jezika}
\cvlanguage{Hrvatski}{Materinji jezik}{}
\cvlanguage{Engleski}{Aktivan u jeziku i pismu}{}
\cvlanguage{Njemački}{Pasivan u jeziku i pismu}{}

\section{Računalne vještine}
\cvcomputer{Operativni sustavi}{Windows, UNIX(Linux), izvrsno poznavanje rada operativnih sustava}{}{}
\cvcomputer{Programiranje}{Osnove rada u Phythonu}{}{}
\cvcomputer{WEB dizajn}{HTML}{}{}
\cvcomputer{Office paketi}{Znanje rada s Wordom, Excellom, Powerpointom}{}{}
\cvcomputer{Adobe}{Poznavanje rada s Adobe Photoshopom, Illustratorom i InDesignom}{}{}
\cvcomputer{Hardware}{PC, mreže}{}{}

\renewcommand{\listitemsymbol}{-} % change the symbol for lists

\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{publications}       % 'publications' is the name of a BibTeX file

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that enables us to reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is because of the way `\cvcomputer` is defined. From cvmodern.cls:

```
% usage (inside 'computer skills' cvsection environment): \cvcomputer{category}{programs}{category}{programs}
\newcommand*{\cvcomputer}[4]{%
  \cvdoubleitem{#1}{\small#2}{#3}{\small#4}}
```

So let's see how `\cvdoubleitem` is defined:

```
% usage: \cvdoubleitem{subtitle}{text}{subtitle}{text}
\newcommand*{\cvdoubleitem}[4]{%
 \cvline{#1}{\begin{minipage}[t]{\doubleitemmaincolumnwidth}#2\end{minipage}%
 \hfill%
 \begin{minipage}[t]{\hintscolumnwidth}\raggedleft\hintfont{#3}\end{minipage}\hspace*{\separatorcolumnwidth}\begin{minipage}[t]{\doubleitemmaincolumnwidth}#4\end{minipage}}}
```

While I didn't bother to understand all of this, the `minipage`s and a look at the [CTAN template](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/moderncv/examples/template.pdf) tells me that this type of entry is geared toward a two-column layout, presumably because the author assumed computer entries won't be very long.

[image: screenshot from the template]

If you don't want the two-column layout, I recommend redefining `\cvcomputer` like this:

```
\renewcommand{\cvcomputer}[2]{\cvline{#1}{\small#2}}
```

Make sure you remove the third and fourth arguments, which are empty, from your source. Your section would be like this:

```
\renewcommand{\cvcomputer}[2]{\cvline{#1}{\small#2}}
\section{Računalne vještine}
\cvcomputer{Operativni sustavi}{Windows, UNIX(Linux), izvrsno poznavanje rada operativnih sustava}
\cvcomputer{Programiranje}{Osnove rada u Phythonu}
\cvcomputer{WEB dizajn}{HTML}
\cvcomputer{Office paketi}{Znanje rada s Wordom, Excellom, Powerpointom}
\cvcomputer{Adobe}{Poznavanje rada s Adobe Photoshopom, Illustratorom i InDesignom}
\cvcomputer{Hardware}{PC, mreže}
```

[image]

BUT, why not make use of the two-column layout? Then, don't use the redefinition and just reorder the arguments:

```
\section{Računalne vještine}
\cvcomputer{Operativni sustavi}{Windows, UNIX(Linux), izvrsno poznavanje rada operativnih sustava}{Office paketi}{Znanje rada s Wordom, Excellom, Powerpointom}
\cvcomputer{Programiranje}{Osnove rada u Phythonu}{Adobe}{Poznavanje rada s Adobe Photoshopom, Illustratorom i InDesignom}
\cvcomputer{WEB dizajn}{HTML}{Hardware}{PC, mreže}
```

[image]

Comment: This worked, but now the \cvlanguage column is messed up :\

Comment: Does my updated answer help?

Answer (score 5):

I just so happened to find this solution posted elsewhere.  I used this `\renewcommand`.

```
\renewcommand*{\cvcomputer}[3]{%

\cvline{#1}{\begin{minipage}[t]{0.9\maincolumnwidth}\textbf{#2}\end{minipage}\hfill\begin{minipage}[t]{0.1\maincolumnwidth}\raggedleft\footnotesize\itshape #3\end{minipage}}}
```

Apparently your `\maincolumnwidth` values should add up to one.  So if you change one value you should change the other.  Using 0.9 and 0.1 looks like it worked.  You can tweak it to your own tastes.

You should be able to apply this to other fields as well by changing `\cvcomputer` to `\cvlanguage` etc.

Comment: This is giving me error: File ended while scanning use of \@argdef :\

Comment: Perhaps I lost something when I copied and pasted the code.  Here I made it a bit more explicit where the linebreak goes.  Also, I inserted this inside the document body right before the section containing `\cvcomputer`.