# reusing code from moderncv

Tags: moderncv

I am a beginner for creating latex templates. I am using a custom template for CV. And I would like to create a table which looks like below. I like the way the text wraps in the columns. This is taken from `moderncv` latex template. I tried to copy the code from `moderncv` template in order to create this table. However,I was not able to do it, because it generated some errors which I was unable to resolve. I read about a similar question which is mentioned [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31249/moderncv-how-to-adjust-the-description-columns). However it did not help my problem.

[image]

I will try to provide a MWE here -

```
\documentclass[]{temp}

\begin{document}

\singleitem{Hardware Platforms}{Intel MPSoC for Wireless USB, TI MPSoC for VOIP, Freescale IMX31, MIPS32, ATMEL, ARM 7, Microblaze}
\singleitem{Development Tools}{GCC, Rose Compiler, Xilinx ISE,  Logic Analyzer, LeCroy USB Tracer, Ellisys Wireless-USB Tracer,  Atmel AVR Studio}
\singleitem{Languages}{C, C++, Linux Shell Scripts, VHDL, Assembly,  SystemC, Java}
\singleitem{Operating Systems}{Linux, VxWorks, RTLinux, MQX, RedBoot}
\singleitem{Protocols}{PCI, USB, Wireless USB, RS 232, SPI, I2C, Ethernet}
\singleitem{Other}{Clearcase, SVN}

\end{document}
```

Here is the short template file which I am using.

```
\LoadClass{article}
\RequirePackage[left=6.1cm,top=2cm,right=1.5cm,bottom=2.5cm,nohead,nofoot]{geometry}    

\newlength{\columnWidth}
\setlength{\columnWidth}{320pt}

\newcommand*{\singleitem}[2]{%
 \begin{minipage}[t]{50pt}\raggedleft{\fontsize{7pt}{7pt}{#1}}\end{minipage}\hspace*{30pt}\begin{minipage}[t]{\columnWidth}#2\end{minipage}
\vspace{5pt}}
```

The PDF it produces has somewhat cluttered appearance.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I did a hack to solve the problem I had. I modified the singleitem command as given below -

```
\newcommand*{\singleitem}[2]{%
 \begin{minipage}[t]{50pt}\raggedleft{\fontsize{7pt}{7pt}{#1}}\end{minipage}\hspace*{30pt}\vspace{5pt}\begin{minipage}[t]{\columnWidth}#2\end{minipage}
\vspace{5pt}}
```